# Prevent Looping Inside Geocoder Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, loops, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I'm using Google Map API. I want to get lat and long with a given address. I did this

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'Stockholm' }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.nb;
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.ob;
            console.log(latitude);
        }
});
```

However i get that console log run repeatedly. I just want to have it running once, but i didn't find any idea.

Comment: The code as you've added it here will run once per geocode request. Perhaps if you add your whole code to a jsfiddle we might have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: is there any way to run only the first request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a new variable that shows whether the geocoding has been called, and change it to true the first time this happens.

```
var geoCalled = false;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'Stockholm' }, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.nb;
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.ob;
    if (!geoCalled) {
      console.log(latitude);
      geoCalled = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I have thought about it before, yet it won't work since the callback function runs asynchronously. So, geoCalled var is undefined because it is in different scope

Comment: I don't think so. `geoCalled` will always be either `false` or `true`; the scope is irrelevant. Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/3r4b3/59/) to see what I mean.